Why does std::vector::assign not free existing allocated memory as soon as possible?
According to cppreference, std::vector::assign replaces the contents with count copies of value value.  This definition implies that the existing state of the vector is not used in assign.
In the following example code run on GCC 14.2, test1 prints 20000002.  This indicates existing memory is deleted after the new space is allocated.  With well-placed clear() & shrink_to_fit() calls, test2 reduces the peak object count and prints 10000002.
Is this a missed optimization opportunity in the implementation of libstdc++ or is my understanding of std::vector functions incorrect/incomplete?
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int curr;
int max;

void update(int delta) { curr += delta; max = std::max(max, curr); }
void reset() { curr = max = 0; }

struct Foo {
    Foo() { update(1); }
    Foo(const Foo&) { update(1); }
    Foo& operator=(const Foo&) { return *this; }
    ~Foo() { update(-1); }
};

void test1() 
{
    reset();
    std::vector<Foo> foos;
    foos.assign(10'000'000, Foo{});
    foos.assign(10'000'001, Foo{});
    std::cout << max << '\n';
}

void test2() 
{
    reset();
    std::vector<Foo> foos;
    foos.assign(10'000'000, Foo{});
    foos.clear();
    foos.shrink_to_fit();
    foos.assign(10'000'001, Foo{});
    std::cout << max << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    test1();
    test2();
    return 0;
}


Neither of vector API releases a memory except shrink_to_fit() and the destructor.

@NathanOliver, that is not true.  At the end of test1, the capacity of foos is 10,000,001.

nvm, noticed you aren't actually printing the capacity

test1 is printing 10000002 on my machine (using clang).  Could be a missed optimization opportunity on your machine (using gcc).  Maybe they're using the temp-and-swap idiom.

So what is the state of the vector if one of the assignment operators throws an exception?

@3CxEZiVlQ I think that even shrink_to_fit does not guarantee memory release ("it is a non-binding request to reduce capacity() to size(). It depends on the implementation whether the request is fulfilled."). I believe only the destructor guarantees it.

Imagine bad_alloc is raised? Or other exception is raised during creating new values.

@MarshallClow, that is an excellent question.  FWIW, adding noexcept in the example code does not change the answer.  Of course, new may throw an exception, which means that it is not safe to delete existing memory until at least the new allocation completes.

Better demo.

Putting memory away takes time. getting it back when you need it again takes even more time. It's generally better to hold onto it, at least for a little while.

During assign it is likely written as create-swap-release as it is an exception safe process - which explains the results in test1. Normally, compiler should be able to optimise it out when exceptions are not possible, however due to your object-count tracking it is impossible for compiler to perform as it alters observable behaviour.

The only member function or operator of std::vector that is guaranteed to release memory is the destructor (even shrink_to_fit() is a non-binding request).     And that only releases memory as far as the program is concerned, and does not guarantee release to the host system.

The observed 20mil mean that there was a moment, when second assign created objects, but objects of first assign were not yet deleted.
And indeed, the second assign is bigger. So if vector allocates exact amount of memory for first assign, then for the second assign it should create another block of memory. Where it will create second load of objects, increasing value of max to 20 mil.
And then it releases memory allocated for first 10 mil elements.
It will not free the first memory block earlier, because during construction of the second memory block there may be an exception.
So the first memory block is released just when it is guaranteed, that allocation and filling of the second memory block succeeded.
Your question is correct: assign doesn't give a strong exception guarantee, i.e. if the second assign would not require a reallocation, then there most probably wouldn't be a reallocation.
But if reallocation is inevitable, they go with a strong guarantee.
Here is explanation, what happened with numbers:
void test1() 
{
    reset();
    std::vector<Foo> foos;
    
    foos.assign(10'000'000, Foo{});
    // allocated underlying memory for first bunch of elements
    // constructed first 10mil elements

    foos.assign(10'000'001, Foo{});
    // allocated underlying memory for second bunch of elements
    // constructed second 10mil elements,
    // max reached 20mil
    //then released first 10mil elements and their underlying memory 
    std::cout << max << '\n';
}

void test2() 
{
    reset();
    std::vector<Foo> foos;
    foos.assign(10'000'000, Foo{}); // constructed first 10 mil elements, `curr` == 10mil
    foos.clear(); // deleted elements, reducing `curr` to 0.
    foos.shrink_to_fit(); // released underlying memory
    foos.assign(10'000'001, Foo{});
    // allocated underlying memory for 10mil+1 elements
    // constructed those elements, `curr` modified from 0 to 10mil+1
    std::cout << max << '\n'; // prints 10mil+1
}


the first group will be destroyed after the second is successfully constructed.
Because if during the second bunch construction there will be an exception, the first bunch should remain untouched.

Oh never mind, I misunderstood OP's code.  This all makes sense.

Perhaps you could test what would happen if Foo{} was nothrow-movable, since that should make it unnecessary to create two separate huge allocations for the purpose of exception safety.
